# How to run nested left join in mysql

Tags: mysql, database, left-join

I have three tables, likes, users and statuses. So I am returning from likes tables and joining `likes table with user table` to see who liked it and joining `likes table with statuses table` to see who posted it.

Now want to get the user information from `status table` to see who wrote the status. Here comes the problem.

SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d0707b/2

My current query

```
select l.*,  s.* , a.id as aid, a.userName from likes l
left join 
    statuses s on l.source_id = s.id
left join 
   users a on l.user_id = a.id
where 
   l.user_id in (5,7) 
or
   (s.privacy='Public' and s.interest in ('mobile', 'andriod') )

order by l.id desc
```

`Here s.user_id=a.id` I want to join the statuses table with user table.

[If question is not clear please comment, will try to edit]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make a join to the `user` table again. Take a look here:

```
SELECT
    l.*, s.*,
    a.id AS aid,
    a.userName,
    b.userName
FROM
    likes l
LEFT JOIN statuses s ON l.source_id = s.id
LEFT JOIN users a ON l.user_id = a.id
LEFT JOIN users b ON s.user_id = b.id
WHERE
    l.user_id IN (5, 7)
OR (
    s.privacy = 'Public'
    AND s.interest IN ('mobile', 'andriod')
)
ORDER BY
    l.id DESC
```